# Is the current warty-final-ubuntu wallpaper going to be like that until the final release?

Tags: 11.04, desktop-background, design

Is the current natty's warty-final-ubuntu wallpaper going to be like that until the final release?

Answer (score 4):

Yes.  It is subtly different from 10.10's wallpaper.  See http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/03/ubuntu-11-04-nattys-new-default-desktop-wallpaper-revealed/ for a side-by-side.